# Why VBox.getChildren.addAll(); not working on Button clicked?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to pass the parameter to other child of VBox. Let me describe the problem.
Here is the onMouseClicked code.

```
viewButton.setOnMouseClicked((event)->{
    try{
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/students/Students.fxml"));
      loader.load();
      StudentsController ctrl = loader.getController();
      ctrl.gotoViewStudent();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

});
```

Here is the gotoViewStudent(); code.

```
public void gotoViewStudent(){
        try {
            System.out.println("get");
            switcher.getChildren().setAll(FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("/students/ViewStudent.fxml")));
            System.out.println("set");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

switcher is a VBox.

```
@FXML private VBox switcher;
```

Here is the GUI view.

[image]

Now let me describe the problem.
**When I clicked on the left Add Student, Search Student. right VBox changes perfectly. But when I click on View button after searching then it's not working.**

Here is the Design.

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="controller.students.StudentsController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <left>
        <VBox id="leftBar">
            <Label styleClass="heading" text="Students">
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="menuAddStudent" styleClass="leftMenuItem" text="Add Student" onMouseClicked="#switchToAddStudents">
                <graphic>
                    <SVGPath styleClass="leftMenuIcon" content="M15 14.016c2.672 0 8.016 1.313 8.016 3.984v2.016h-16.031v-2.016c0-2.672 5.344-3.984 8.016-3.984zM6 9.984h3v2.016h-3v3h-2.016v-3h-3v-2.016h3v-3h2.016v3zM15 12c-2.203 0-3.984-1.781-3.984-3.984s1.781-4.031 3.984-4.031 3.984 1.828 3.984 4.031-1.781 3.984-3.984 3.984z"/>
                </graphic>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="menuSearchStudent" styleClass="leftMenuItem" id="paddingLeft" text="Search Student" onMouseClicked="#switchToSearchStudents">
                <graphic>
                    <SVGPath styleClass="leftMenuIcon" content="M9.516 14.016c2.484 0 4.5-2.016 4.5-4.5s-2.016-4.5-4.5-4.5-4.5 2.016-4.5 4.5 2.016 4.5 4.5 4.5zM15.516 14.016l4.969 4.969-1.5 1.5-4.969-4.969v-0.797l-0.281-0.281c-1.125 0.984-2.625 1.547-4.219 1.547-3.609 0-6.516-2.859-6.516-6.469s2.906-6.516 6.516-6.516 6.469 2.906 6.469 6.516c0 1.594-0.563 3.094-1.547 4.219l0.281 0.281h0.797z"/>
                </graphic>
            </Label>
        </VBox>
    </left>
    <center>
        <VBox id="rightContent" fx:id="switcher">
            <Label text="Students Static"/>
        </VBox>
    </center>
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@../../resource/stylesheets/base.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
</BorderPane>
```

and Here is the controller associated with it.

```
package controller.students;

import java.io.IOException;

import application.Paths;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class StudentsController {
    @FXML private VBox switcher;
    @FXML private Label menuAddStudent;
    @FXML private Label menuSearchStudent;

    @FXML
    public void switchToAddStudents(MouseEvent event){
        try {
            switcher.getChildren().setAll(FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource(""+Paths.MOVE_UP+Paths.VIEWS+"/students/AddStudent.fxml")));
            clickSelected("addStudent");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void switchToSearchStudents(MouseEvent event){
        try {
            switcher.getChildren().setAll(FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource(""+Paths.MOVE_UP+Paths.VIEWS+"/students/SearchStudent.fxml")));
            clickSelected("searchStudent");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void gotoViewStudent(){
        try {
            System.out.println("get");
            switcher.getChildren().setAll(FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource(""+Paths.MOVE_UP+Paths.VIEWS+"/students/AddStudent.fxml")));
            System.out.println("set");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void clickSelected(String menu){
        if(menu.equalsIgnoreCase("addStudent")){
            clearOtherMenuItem();
            menuAddStudent.getStyleClass().setAll("selectedLeftMenu");
        }else if(menu.equalsIgnoreCase("searchStudent")){
            clearOtherMenuItem();
            menuSearchStudent.getStyleClass().setAll("selectedLeftMenu");
        }
    }
    private void clearOtherMenuItem(){
        menuAddStudent.getStyleClass().setAll("leftMenuItem");
        menuSearchStudent.getStyleClass().setAll("leftMenuItem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems strange to me that you're loading a scene just to throw everything but the controller away (`viewButton.setOnMouseClicked`)... Or does the `initialize` method of the controller do anything that shows the scene?

Comment: @fabian Basically I'm not loading scene or anything. I'm just changing the children of VBox as I shown in image. When I click on the leftbar buttons then changing of content happens fine as `switchToSearchStudent` method. But when I try to change it with View Button then nothing happens.

Comment: But `switcher` is not displayed in the UI (since you discarded the entire hierarchy containing it). So `switcher.getChildren().setAll(...)` will have no visible effect.

Comment: @James_D no I didn't discarded it. See the FXML code Inside that you will see the `VBox` with `fx:id="switcher"` When I click on the left menu. Add Student, etc switcher's child changes fines but when I click on `View` Button after searching result, then it is not changing. How I can change? I need to call gotoViewStudent() method. I tried but that's not working.

Comment: Sure you are discarding it: you do `loader.load()` and don't even save the result to a variable, never mind show it in the UI. Then you get the controller associated with the UI instance you just loaded, but didn't display, and change the contents of the (still not displayed) vbox inside it by calling `gotoViewStudent()`. You're just altering an instance of the UI that is never displayed.

Comment: @James_D I need to change switcher's child how I can? because I want to show student complete information on the other FXML when I click on `View` button. any code example?

Comment: I don't know where `viewButton` is defined, so it's not possible to give a complete answer, but you need to arrange for the controller that has access to `viewButton` to have access to the *existing* `StudentsController` (not an arbitrary instance you just load on the fly). (Better still would be to use a "View Model" and something along the lines of a MVVM pattern.)

Comment: Ok I will try to solve it. But I use my own logic to create such application like clicking on Top Menu Icons to change content, then click on left Add Student to change the right side. All this is happening by changing the children of Nodes(etc)(event not a single screen). How I can such app in better Design? can you give me a link that could help me to build such app in better way?

Comment: [This blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1) is quite popular.

Comment: I already visited that link, But is difficult to understand for me.

Comment: Well, that's up to you to study it and understand it. All the source code is available. No-one can understand it for you.

Comment: Yes I know, I was expecting easy one. Anyhow thanks for your time.

Comment: @James_D I read that post and close to understand. I want to ask the question how I can create framework as in my application? Like all screens should have the same Menu top Box Icons. Should I include it on all screens?